# Slow jackson performance for deserializing small list/array

Tags: json, jackson, json-deserialization

Using jackson for android, trying deserialize small arrays (300~600 elements).
The performance is terrible, is takes around 8 seconds per list.
I look in the source code and it seems jackson does not allocate the list/array size before hand. I think that is the problem. Is there a way to give initial capacity for these list/arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the debugger, it was making the deserialization slower.
when I run it without the debugger it is ~50% faster and ~70% in release mode.